# Incorrect MAC address on DHCP

Tags: networking, printer, dhcp, mac-address

Recently I experienced an issue:

A Label Printer shows up as offline and users cannot print from it.
The MAC address of the printer was given to someone who reserved a DHCP lease for it.
I restarted the device and checked its ip, it didnt pick up the lease.

I manually set the ip of the device and updated the print server and it came online, printing out the labels.

The infrastructure technician checked the DHCP list and checked for the ip of the machine.
The MAC address on the DHCP list did not match the MAC of the actual machine

Is there any reason for this?
I don't believe any part of this is virtualised, the mac address is not spoofed, all devices are ethernet/lan.
What could possibly be going on?

Comment: Sounds like human err when reserving the DHCP lease and the wrong MAC address was used.

Comment: My initial thought was the same, I asked the technician to confirm the lease and he checked the DHCP record which displayed the ip of the printer and a different mac address, so it cant be an error reserving the address

Comment: Is the device in question actually a standalone networked printer, or is it a _computer_ running e.g. Linux with the printer USB/COM-attached to it? Also, what MAC address is the technician seeing in the list – is it from the same manufacturer, etc? (Is it even a MAC address at all, or something several bytes longer?)

Comment: It is a dedicated, networked, label printer. The MAC address is completely different, even the manufacturer code (first few digits) is different. Its very strange!!

If there was a repeater in between the printer and print server/dhcp server how would i tell? 
Its the only possible thing I can think of it being.

If anyone has any other ideas, even remotely possible, please mention it